# how to stringify an ArrayList<String> to do a sqlite query?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist

How can I take an ArrayList and turn it sqlite approved?

I tried the following two methods and neither work, but one works for longs:

Method 1:

```
Arrays.deepToString(ids.toArray()).replace("[", "(").replace("]", ")");
```

Method 2:

```
Arrays.toString(ids.toArray()).replace("[", "(").replace("]", ")");
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just:

```
String inQuery = ids.toString().replace("[", "(").replace("]", ")");
```